# What is 'while' doing in this program?

Tags: c, while-loop

This is a C program to find Arithmetic mean of discrete frequency distribution.
The Program runs as its supposed to, but cant understand what is the role of 'While' in this program in main() function.

```
void main()
{
  int choice;
  while(1)
  {

  printf("\n\tThe Mean for Discrete Distribution ");
  printf("\n\n1.Direct Method \n2.Shortcut Method \n0.Exit ");
  printf("\nEnter your choice: ");
  scanf("%d",&choice);

  switch(choice)
  {
    case 1:
      getdata();
      direct();
      break;

    case 2:
      getdata();
      shortcut();
      break;

    case 0:
      exit(0);
      break;

    default:
      printf("\nEnter valid choice!");
      break;
   }

  }
}
```

The program runs perfectly well, But I just dont understant what 'while' is doing  here. The program is very huge, Hence I didnt wrote the functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `while(1)` always evaluates to `true`, this program continuously prompts the user "*Enter yours choice*" until the user hits `0`. When `0` is entered whole program stops because call to function `exit(0)` will be made.

Answer (score 2):

It keeps the program running until the user inputs 0 and exit(0) is called.

Comment: Thank you for answering, how would you depict that in a flowchart?

Comment: @VengenceTech, one Q&A at a time.

Comment: @jwdonahue   OK will post another one.